# Storing random values to an array

Tags: java, arrays, random

Revised question:
I want the even elements of my array to be stored in a corresponding array. My if else statements do that. Since there will always be a varying number of evens and odds each run, I want the size of the `evenArray` and `oddArray` to adjust with each iteration of my while loop. I get an error when compiling that says I'm not doing that part right.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random; 
public class randomdemo { 
    public static int[] randommethod()
    {
        int i = 0;

        int[] myArray;
        myArray = new int[100];

        int[] evenArray;

        int[] oddArray;

        while(i<=99)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(25) + 0;
            myArray[i] = n;

            if(myArray[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                evenArray = new int[i];
                evenArray[i] = n;
            }
            else
            {
                oddArray = new int[i];
                oddArray[i] = n;
            }

            i++;
        }

        return myArray;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] result = randommethod();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        randommethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: You never ask the program to print anything (such as using a method like `println`). It's therefore expected that nothing is printed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the result, and maybe print it. Your could use a loop or [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29). Something like,

```
int[] result = randommethod();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

When I put both lines in `main()` and use your posted `randommethod()` it appears to work.

Comment: I have another quick question about the program. See the edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Java arrays are not dynamically sized data structures. You can't do that. You could size them both the same as the input (and leave empty slots). Or, you could use a `Collection` like an `ArrayList<Integer>` which is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

The returned array is not being used.

So the return from `randommethod()` is an `int[]` but the main method does not print it (or use it in any way).

Here is one way to use it:

```
int[] outputRandomAry = randommethod();
for (int elem : outputRandomAry) {
  System.out.print(elem + ", ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Also you might want to put the `Random rand = new Random(); //using the random class` outside the while loop. This prevents unnecessary spinning off new objects for each rand.

And you can use `int n = rand.nextInt(26);` for 0(inclusive) to 26(exclusive) gives you the desired range.

Comment: Can you explain some more?

Comment: @YoungDeezie I have edited the answer to include further details.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the array without storing, **write** this **in** the **main**. 
**100% it will work.**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randommethod()));  //print array
```

---

At this line, you returned the vaule:

```
return myArray; //returns the array
```

But you **did not store it** anywhere. So the return value is lost. Even though you did all the work in the method.

Store your return array as follows in the **main**

```
int[] myArray = randommethod();    //store returned value (from method)
```

After that, you can do anything you want with the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the things mentioned by other user, if I were you, I will write your method this way:

```
public static int[] randommethod()      //declaring method
{
    Random rnd = new Random();          //using the random class
    int[] myArray = new int[100];       //create and initializing array in 1 line

    for(int x=0; x<myArray.length; x++) //Normally use for-loop when you know how many times to iterate
        myArray[x] = rnd.nextInt(26);   //0-25 has 26 possibilities, so just write 26 here

    return myArray;                     //returns the array
}
```

It will do exactly the same thing, I am editing this from your original codes.

**In the main..**

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = randommethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a random int between 0 and 25 inclusive, then your code should be:

```
int n = rand.nextInt(26); //I want a random int between 0 and 25 inclusive
```